# Cancel a pending computer name change in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

While attempting to troubleshoot some issues, I changed the name of a server using the System Properties window (Control Panel > System > Change settings > Computer Name > Change...).

After making this change I did not restart the machine, so the name change is still pending a restart. The issue has since been resolved, so I no longer need to change the computer name. However, the option to change the name is now disabled until I restart the machine.

I'd like to know if there's a way to "cancel" this pending name change and just leave the name as it was. Some Googling implies there is a single registry entry I could change, but I want to make sure I cover all my bases.

Comment: I would simple restart the server, sign onto it, change the name back to what it needs to be, and then restart it again and you're all set.... NEXT!! It makes no sense to try to find some hack that's undocumented, etc. or advised against to revert the OS operation you needed it to complete in the first place. Just complete it as it was designed for this function and move on. ~Respectfully

Comment: That will be my solution if I can't find an alternative before the end of the day. This server is running some production software which is in use today, so I'd like to avoid restarting it if I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check this registry key:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName
```

And make it the same to this one:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName
```

Then the Server will cancel the change and keep it's actual Hostname.

[Source](https://serverfault.com/a/531823).

Comment: Indeed, I have done this in old Server OSes in the GUI, just repeating the process of changing the name, and putting the old name back in!  The same idea might work in PowerShell, but I haven't tested that.  The best answer is of course not to rename improperly in the first place :-P

Comment: Just FYI, some additionals keys may need to be modified. I had to also modify `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\NV Hostname` so the GUI won't says "the computer name will change". See this script for a list: https://gist.github.com/timnew/2373475